# GitKraken and Kubuntu - installs but doesn't run

Tags: kubuntu

I just tried to install GitKraken, but it doesn't run on Kubuntu 16.04.

When I run the program in terminal, I get the output:

```
state:  update-not-available
App load time: 448ms
state:  checking-for-update
```

At which point it freezes.

The linux_update file in /Home/.gitkraken contains the code:

```
{"update_url":"https://release.gitkraken.com/linux/RELEASES"}
```

Perhaps this is where the problem is occurring? The URL seems fine when I try to follow it myself. It simply is a download link for a RELEASES file that contains:

```
{"name":"1.4.1","url_deb":"http://release.gitkraken.com/linux/v1.4.1.deb","url_targz":"http://release.gitkraken.com/linux/v1.4.1.tar.gz"}
```

Any idea on why this is happening? Has anyone else experienced the same issue?

Comment: Please give more details : What do you mean by "it doesn't run"

Comment: Like I launch the app and the app tries to launch but then crashes and closes. Surprised I am the only one that cannot run this app...

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential clang libdbus-1-dev libgtk2.0-dev \
                       libnotify-dev libgnome-keyring-dev libgconf2-dev \
                       libasound2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libxtst-dev \
                       libxss1 libnss3-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib curl

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893100/cant-install-gitkraken

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I fixed it by running `gitkraken -l` from the terminal. this gave me an error of `libgnome-keyring.so.0: cannot open shared object file` so I fixed it by installing the libraries with `sudo apt install libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring-dev` . Unfortunately I don't have the required reputation to post an answer on this question.

Comment: @DazBaldwin: thanks, man - you saved my gitten kraken life!

Comment: @code4life no worries. Still don't have the required rep to post it as an answer though =0[

Comment: @DazBaldwin Looks like you have enough now!

Comment: @JakeReece unfortunately not. it doesn't count the association bonus and I don't seem to have gotten any rep for my useful comment votes. `(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻`

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing `libgnome-keyring` try installing it with:

```
sudo apt install libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring-dev
```